# how to put dash after certain digit is insert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is html code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="telnumber" maxlength="20" />

<script>
    $('.telnumber').keyup(function() {
        foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
        foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}$|.{1,2}$|.{1,6}', 'g')).join("-");
        $(this).val(foo);
    });
</script>
```

I want my output like this `528228-25-5258`.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: i want my output like this 999999-99-9999

Comment: plenty of masking scripts out there

Comment: Very difficult to do without making the UI a disaster.

Comment: If you're going to format the text as the user types it, you really need to note the cursor position and set it back there after inserting the hyphens (adjusting for the hyphens, of course), otherwise it's annoying for the user when they try to edit an existing value. Also, note that the user can edit the field without using the keyboard.

Comment: Why is `maxlength` set to `"20"` if expected input is `"528228-25-5258"`  which is `.length` `14`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for the following solution, there are a few keypoints to understand.

- First, I changed the event to `oninput` so that the event fires whenever the input on the textbox changes, instead that when a key is lifted.
- Second, instead of using regexes, I simply made a new string based on the old one where we insert a dash on the string if it is long enough (6 or 8 characters, according to your specifications)
- Third, we split the input into an array and then join it again after we have inserted the hyphens where necessary.

Here is the solution:
https://codepen.io/SammyIsra/pen/bWgWZq

Comment: _"I want my output like this `528228-25-5258`."_ `javascript` at codepen allows `099999-99-9999999999` for input. Is this valid according to OP?

Comment: You're right, I mistakenly ignored the length of the input. I've modified the Codepen, it should limit the input to 14 digits now (666666-22-4444)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}` to match six digits followed by dash `"-"` followed by two digits followed by dash `"-"` followed by four digits; `maxlength` should be set to `14` instead of `20`; set `placeholder` to expected `.value` `999999-99-9999`; use `input` event to check `this.validity.patternMismatch`, if `false`, set `<input type="text">` to `disabled`, show sibling element `<input type="reset">` where at `click` event `<input type="text">` `.value` is set top empty string `""`. Utilize adjacent `<label>` element with `for` attribute set to `id` of `<input type="text">` to display notifications to user.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="text" class="telnumber" id="tel" maxlength="14" pattern="\d{6}-\d{2}-\d{4}" placeholder="999999-99-9999"/><label for="tel">Invalid input <code>999999-99-9999</code></label>
    <input type="reset">

    <script>
        $(".telnumber").on("input", function(e) {       
          if (!this.validity.patternMismatch) {
             this.labels[0].innerHTML = "Valid input";
             this.disabled = !this.validity.patternMismatch;
             $(this).siblings("input[type=reset]").show().one("click", function() {
               e.target.disabled = false;
               e.target.value = "";
               e.target.labels[0].innerHTML = "Invalid input <code>999999-99-9999</code>";
               $(this).hide();
             })
          };        
        }).siblings("input[type=reset]").hide()
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```